# Case insensitive string matching in awk

Tags: string, awk, matching, case-sensitive, lowercase

Assume a multi-line text file `file` in which some lines start with whitespaces.

```
$ cat file
foo Baz
  baz QUX
    QUx Quux
BaZ Qux
BazaaR
```

Further assume that I wish to convert all those lines that start with a keyword (e.g. "*baz*") to lowercase letters, irrespective if (a) that keyword is written in lower- or uppercase letters (or any combination thereof) itself, and (b) that keyword is preceeded by whitespaces.

```
$ cat file | sought_command
foo Baz        # not to lowercase (line does not start with keyword)
  baz qux      # to lowercase
    QUx Quux
baz qux        # to lowercase
BazaaR         # not to lowercase (line does not start with keyword, but merely with a word containing the keyword)
```

I believe that **awk** is the tool to do it, but I am uncertain how to implement the case-insensitivity for the keyword matching.

```
$ cat file | awk '{ if($1 ~ /^ *baz/) print tolower($0); else print $0}'
foo Baz
  baz qux
    QUx Quux
BaZ Qux       # ERROR HERE: was not replaced, b/c keyword not recognized.
BazaaR
```

**EDIT 1**:
Adding `IGNORECASE=1` appears to resolve the case-insensitivity, but now incorrectly converts the last line to lowercase.

```
$ cat file | awk '{IGNORECASE=1; if($1~/^ *baz/) print tolower($0); else print $0}'
foo Baz
  baz qux
    QUx Quux
baz qux
bazaar       # ERROR HERE: should not be converted to lowercase, as keyword not present (emphasis on word!).
```

Comment: I don't know whether awk does support case-insensitive match (as some other regex dialects do). But this should work: `/^ *[bB][aA][zZ]/`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already know about `tolower()` so just use it again in the comparison and test for an exact string match instead of partial regexp:

```
awk 'tolower($1)=="baz"{$0=tolower($0)}1'
```

Answer (score 8):

Add word-boundary after search string

```
$ awk '{IGNORECASE=1; if($1~/^ *baz\>/) print tolower($0); else print $0}' ip.txt 
foo Baz
  baz qux
    QUx Quux
baz qux
BazaaR
```

Can be re-written as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /^ *baz\>/{$0=tolower($0)} 1' ip.txt
```

Since line anchor is used, no need to match with `$1`. The `1` at end will print the record, including any changes done

`IGNORECASE` and `\>` are `gawk` specific features. `\y` can be also used to match word boundary

With `GNU sed`

```
$ sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*baz\b.*/\L&/I' ip.txt 
foo Baz
  baz qux
    QUx Quux
baz qux
BazaaR
```

- `[[:blank:]]` will match space or tab characters
- `\L&` will lowercase the line
- `\b` is word boundary
- `I` flag to match case-insensitively

Comment: I'm impressed (especially about `IGNORECASE`). Regarding your awk sample: `\>` is word boundary?

Comment: actually OP mentioned about IGNORECASE in edit... and yeah `\>` matches ending position of word

Comment: His edit appeared just in the same minute like your answer. Thus, I was not sure where to direct my impression to. You won because of the `\>`...

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks for the detailed answer. As a follow-up regarding your **awk** solution: How can I enforce the conversion to lowercase letters given the explained keyword matching if (and only if) the line is terminated by a semi-colon. For example: `BaZ Qux;` is converted to `baz qux;`, whereas  `BaZ Qux` is not.

Comment: @MichaelGruenstaeudl you can combine conditions logically... so `/^ *baz\>/ && /;$/`..